# Php -- quick explanation how to use webpage.php?error=1

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I can't find this anywhere right now and looking for a quick answer.

What is the functionality of using webpagename.php?error=1?

Basically I want to use it so that when an error occurs logging in, I can redirect them to the page with a different message saying error.

I tried using

```
header('Location: loginpage.php');
echo '<p class="error">Error Logging In!</p>';
```

but nothing ever shows up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in two way you can do this!

-1:

use like that parameter in URL

```
header('Location: loginpage.php?error=1');
```

in loginpage.php in JavaScript section check URL is contain error or not!

look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314383/how-to-check-if-a-querystring-value-is-present-via-javascript)

just replace "q" with error!

make a function and check if contain error

show a error message!

```
<script>
function logincheck(){
 // code
}

if(logincheck()){
// do something
//alert('error');
// or append a error in html element
}
</script>
```

you can check this query string in php but JavaScript way is better

-2

use session

after validate set a session with error message
like this:

```
$_SESSION['login_error'] = 'error in login!';
```

and in loginpage.php

check if that session have a value, show that to user,and unset session

like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_error'])){
   echo '<p class="error">Error Logging In!</p>';
   unset($_SESSION['login_error']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when u doing header, you already redirecting to the loginpage.php
you should put the error message at loginpage.php.

or you can hold the redirection by doing something like

```
header('Refresh: 3;url=loginpage.php');
```

which redirect after 3 second;

Answer (score 0):

On the page processing the login check, if login fails:

```
header('Location: loginpage.php?error=1');
```

Inside of loginpage.php place code where you want the message to appear:

```
<?php
If ($_GET['error']==1) {echo "login error!"} elseif ($_GET['error']==2) { echo some other message } .....
?>
```

The purpose of ?error=1 in the url is to pass a variable named ERROR with a value of 1 through the URL which is accessable to the redirection target page through $_GET